# Why when I read from a text file using a for loop, the first letter of the first string goes away?

Tags: c, string, for-loop

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
char readName[500];
char readNumber[500];
char readAdress[500];
char readEmail[500];
int textFileLines;
char c; 
FILE * contactData;
int listContacts()
{
    contactData = fopen("Test.txt", "r+");     
    for (c = getc(contactData); c != EOF; c = getc(contactData)) 
    {
        if (c == '\n') 
        {
            textFileLines = textFileLines + 1; 
        }
    }
    fclose(contactData); 
    if(textFileLines < 4)
    {
    exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
    contactData = fopen("Test.txt", "r+");
    for (c = getc(contactData); c != EOF; c = getc(contactData)) 
    {
    fgets(readName, 500, contactData);
    fgets(readNumber, 500, contactData);
    fgets(readAdress, 500, contactData);
    fgets(readEmail, 500, contactData);
    readNumber[strlen(readNumber) - 1] = '\0';
    readAdress[strlen(readAdress) - 1] = '\0';
    readEmail[strlen(readEmail) - 1] = '\0';
    printf("======================================\n");
    printf("Name: %s", readName);
    printf("Phone Number: %s\n", readNumber);
    printf("Adress: %s\n", readAdress);
    printf("Email: %s\n", readEmail);
    }
    fclose(contactData);
    }
    printf("======================================\n");
    system("pause");
    main();
}

int main() 
{ 
    listContacts();
}
```

So I made this program that prints everything in a text file. However, there is a problem with it.

This is Test.txt.

```
String One
String Two 
String Three
String Four
```

Expected Output:

```
======================================
String One
String Two 
String Three
String Four
======================================
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Actual output:

```
======================================
tring One
String Two
String Three
String Four
======================================
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The only solution was to do make the text file like this.

```
 String One
String Two
String Three
String Four
```

Which makes the program print the expected output.

So, why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

Comment: @Kuronekonova  The second for loop for (c = getc(contactData); c != EOF; c = getc(contactData)) 
    {
    fgets(readName, 500, contactData); does not make a sense. You are skipping the first character. Pay attention to that the variable c shall have the type int. And the variable textFileLines was not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> So, why does this happen

Because you consume a byte in this line:

```
for (c = getc(contactData); c != EOF; c = getc(contactData))
```

> and how can I fix this?

Remove the line and you are done, you don't need to catch `EOF`, `fgets` takes care of that, and since all your arrays are static (placed at global scope and initialized to zero) there is no risk to print garbage (if `fgets` fails it leaves the string untouched), but there is a risk to write at offset -1 in those lines:

```
readNumber[strlen(readNumber) - 1] = '\0';
...
```

switch to

```
readNumber[strcspn(readNumber, "\n")] = '\0';
...
```